# Is a FaceTime Proxy Possible?

Tags: facetime, proxy

I'm wondering if it'd be technically possible to have someone FaceTime a bot and the bot serves as a proxy to FaceTime another number? Similar question with iMessage?

By Proxy I also mean calling the end user from a different number than the call came from.

Comment: A proxy is used to obfuscate the IP.  I think they are confusing it with spoofing

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty difficult, if not impossible.  You see, all the communications with Apple are obviously done with secured SSL APIs.   As difficult as it is to impersonate another user to Apple, it's even more difficult to impersonate Apple to the receiving user, Apple controls the whole software stack.

Obviously a nation state attack could conceivable achieve this but this would surely go via hacking the mobile device of the receiving user.

Comment: I'd be thinking more along the lines of the 'proxy' using two accounts (Apple IDs) simultaneously. One in, one out. I can't honestly see the point of it, but that could perhaps be done at application-level, with some account juggling, maybe across two logins or even 2 Macs, or RDC with a screen recorder etc.

Comment: Couldn't you change the phone number in the system settings to display a different one?  The calls go anyway over the network and not over the mobile operator